# Why does the result set of Informix automatically add blank spaces to the varchar fields?

Tags: informix

Why does the result set of Informix automatically add blank spaces to the varchar fields?
The `trim` function is no use. When inserting such result set into another DB, it would also contain the blank spaces.
How to filter or trim the blank spaces?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a database varchar(n) field, and there are blank chars on the right of the text, they are coming from the application layer, not the engine. (For example, your column is defined as varchar(30) and your application form/screen has a text field of (30).) If the application layer does not provide a varchar field, you might see this.

Take note this is not only valid for Informix; it is valid for any transactional database engine.

Comment: I use datastage to extract data from informix DB, and define varchar in datastage, but there are always trailing blank spaces coming with the result set from the informix. The blank spaces are not in the source fields, but generated after the query is executed.

Comment: Very strange situation. I recommend you to watch for the application that is recording this data into Informix. There should be the problem. Just for the records, you can open a support ticket for help.

Comment: I have no privilege to check the source application.

Comment: Ok, first thing. Check that you are using the correct / compatible Informix Client, on the datastage machine. The default (provided) driver is not updated, so it is recommended you to use a newer one. Do you know what is the Informix engine version? From that, I can tell you what is your supported and recommended driver.

Comment: How to check the version of Informix engine? I just know my datastage version is 8.7

Comment: You should run an "onstat -" as user informix, logged on the Informix server.